# Lots of errors when trying to use a JUnit test case

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, case

So we made a class that given certain values, comes up with certain things. The professor gave us his test cases that he has been using, so we can fix ours so they match up and work properly. I am on eclipse and I've tried to make new JUnit test cases under the packages specified but I keep getting lots of errors in the test case classes, and they aren't being allowed to run as JUnits. It gives an error whenever there is an "@" for example "@Test", or "@Before". Also giving errors on the "asserts" even though I have gone into window, preferences, and clicked the box that allows assertions. I am also getting errors on all the "org.junits" at the beginning

Here is my class that I personally made if this matters at all (not where the errors are)

```
public class DayOfWeek1 {
    int myMonth, myDayOfMonth, myYear, myAdjustment, numericDayOfWeek;
    /*
     * @param what the date was
     */
    public DayOfWeek1(int month, int dayOfMonth, int  year){
        myMonth = month;
        myDayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
        myYear = year;
    }
    /*
     * @return the numeric day of the week
     */
    public int getNumericDayOfWeek(){
        if(myMonth==1){
            myAdjustment = 1;
            if(myYear%4==0){
                myAdjustment-=1;
            }
        }
        if(myMonth==2){
            myAdjustment = 4;
            if(myYear%4==0){
                myAdjustment-=1;
            }
        }
        if(myMonth==3){
            myAdjustment = 4;
        }
        if(myMonth==4){
            myAdjustment = 0;
        }
        if(myMonth==5){
            myAdjustment = 2;
        }
        if(myMonth==6){
            myAdjustment = 5;
        }
        if(myMonth==7){
            myAdjustment = 0;
        }
        if(myMonth==8){
            myAdjustment = 3;
        }
        if(myMonth==9){
            myAdjustment = 6;
        }
        if(myMonth==10){
            myAdjustment = 1;
        }
        if(myMonth==11){
            myAdjustment = 4;
        }
        if(myMonth==12){
            myAdjustment = 6;
        }
        int fourDivides = myYear / 4;
        numericDayOfWeek = myAdjustment + myDayOfMonth + (myYear-1900) + fourDivides; 
        return numericDayOfWeek;

    }
    /*
     * returns what day of the week it was
     */
     public String getDayOfWeek(){
         if(numericDayOfWeek==0){
             return "Saturday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==1){
             return "Sunday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==2){
             return "Monday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==3){
             return "Tuesday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==4){
            return "Wednesday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==5){
            return "Thursday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==6){
             return "Friday";
         }
         else{
             return "NO_VALUE";
         }
     }
     /*
      * @return the month in an int
      */
     public int getMonth(){
         return myMonth;
     }
     /*
      * @return the month in a string
      */
     public String getMonthString(){
         if(myMonth==1){
             return "January";
         }
         if(myMonth==2){
             return "February";
         }
         if(myMonth==3){
             return "March";
         }
         if(myMonth==4){
             return "April";
         }
         if(myMonth==5){
             return "May";
         }
         if(myMonth==6){
             return "June";
         }
         if(myMonth==7){
             return "July";
         }
         if(myMonth==8){
             return "August";
         }
         if(myMonth==9){
             return "September";
         }
         if(myMonth==10){
             return "October";
         }
         if(myMonth==11){
             return "November";
         }
         if(myMonth==12){
             return "December";
         }
         else{
             return "NO_VALUE";
         }
     }
     /*
      * @return what day of the month it was
      */
     public int getDayOfMonth(){
         return myDayOfMonth;
     }
     /*
      * @return what year it was
      */
     public int getYear(){
         return myYear;
     }

}
```

and here is one of the test cases I have to use where the errors are. There are a few others like it.

```
package dayofweektesting;

import dayofweek.DayOfWeek;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;

/**

 */

public class TestInvalidDates {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    /**
     * Test invalid date before first valid date
     */
    @Test
    public void beforeFirstDay() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(12, 31, 1899);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    /**
     * Test invalid date after last valid date
     */
    @Test
    public void afterLastDay() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(1, 1, 2100);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    /**
     * Test invalid date of Feb. 29th when not leap year
     * - year right after a leap year
     */
    @Test
    public void notLeapYearAfter() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 29, 1909);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    /**
     * Test invalid date of Feb. 29th when not leap year
     * - year right between leap years
     */
    @Test
    public void notLeapYearMiddle() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 29, 1910);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    /**
     * Test invalid date of Feb. 29th when not leap year
     * - year right after a leap year
     */
    @Test
    public void notLeapYearBefore() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 29, 1911);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    /**
     * Test invalid 30th and 31st-day-of-month dates.
     *      2/30/2000
     *      2/31/2000
     *      4/31/2000
     *      6/31/2000
     *      9/31/2000
     *      11/31/2000
     */
    @Test
    public void badFebruary30() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 30, 2000);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    @Test
    public void badFebruary31() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(2, 31, 2000);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    @Test
    public void badApril() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(4, 31, 2000);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    @Test
    public void badJune() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(6, 31, 2000);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    @Test
    public void badSeptember() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(9, 31, 2000);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    @Test
    public void badNovember() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(11, 31, 2000);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    /**
     * Test invalid day-of-month (negative)
     */
    @Test
    public void badDOMneg() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(1, -1, 2000);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonth() == DayOfWeek.NO_VALUE);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString() == null);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    /**
     * Test invalid day-of-month (0)
     */
    @Test
    public void badDOM0() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(1, 0, 2000);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonth() == DayOfWeek.NO_VALUE);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString() == null);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    /**
     * Test invalid day-of-month (32)
     */
    @Test
    public void badDOMafter() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(1, 32, 2000);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonth() == DayOfWeek.NO_VALUE);
        assertTrue(dow.getMonthString() == null);
        this.assertBadDOW(dow);
    }

    /*
     * Private helper method to check returned int and String values.
     */
    private void assertBadDOW(DayOfWeek dow)
    {
        assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek() == null);
        assertTrue(dow.getNumericDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.NO_VALUE);
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? thanks

Comment: Whenever posting a question about error messages, please post the error messages.

Comment: Do you have the JUnit jar in the library of your project ?

Comment: Please copy/paste the exact error message!  ALSO: Please take a look at this Most Excellent tutorial, to see if maybe you're missing something: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Most likely you don't have the JUnit library set up as a build dependency.

Comment: The import org.junit cannot be resolved

Comment: Before cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you don't have the JUnit library on the classpath when compiling.  If you're using an IDE, make sure it's set as as a dependency.  (In fact, however you're building things, make sure it's set as a dependency ;) )

Comment: how do i make sure its set as a dependency?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, just spotted you mentioned Eclipse.  You should be able to go to project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library... -> JUnit, and make sure something's selected (probably JUnit 4).